# In elasticsearch 1.7, Is there a performance difference between using the type filter and using the term filter (for the field _type)?

Tags: elasticsearch

Ex:
{
    "type" : {
        "value" : "my_type"
    }
}

vs.
{
    "term" : {
        "_type" : "my_type"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

**[Term filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-term-filter.html) are certainly fast, since they are cached and do not influence the score (`constant_Score`). However, whether they are faster than [type filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-type-filter.html) needs testing on your end.**

I did some testing on my ES 5.2, and found [type queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-type-query.html) (which replaces type filters) have almost equivelant performance compared to [term filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html).

Since it looks like type filter serves this exact purpose (filters documents matching the provided document/mapping type), I'm inclined to say type filters are faster. Of course, we need empirical results to be certain.